# simple form changes collection on reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I use a association in my simple form, but if any error occurs on submit, the form is reloaded, but the collection has changed to dislay only yes/no

My code

```
= simple_form_for([:companies, @view_model.sales_price]) do |f|
  = f.input :name, autofocus: true
  = f.input :margin_percentage
  = f.association :carrier_products, collection: @view_model.carrier_products, as: :check_boxes
  = f.association :customers, as: :check_boxes
```

The carrier_products collection consists of 5 different records. When I click submit, as to activate some of the validation errors, two checkboxes with yes/no is displayed instead of the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have assigned some values to `carrier_products` in the controller `new` or `edit` action (which shows the form the first time), but not in the `create` or `update` action ( which is called on form submit).